# Locate run-time error for array operations and map operations

Tags: arrays, dictionary, ocaml

I use often `array` in my project. I just realize that for an `out of bounds` error in an assignment (e.g. `a.(100) <- 5`), if there is no catching exception, it will silently stop the execution.

I would like to know the place where the error is raised, once every error like occurs. One way to do it is to add `try ... with ...` around array operations, but obviously it is tedious and not good-looking...

Does anyone have a better idea?

Same logic for `map` operations. I notice that for `find` in `map`, if no binding exists, `Not_found` is raised, but if there is no `try ... with ...`, nothing will be explicitly shown. How can I make it explicitly shown systematically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compile your program with debug symbols "-g" and set the environment variable OCAMLRUNPARAM=b. Or use Printexc

Google is your friend:
http://www.mega-nerd.com/erikd/Blog/CodeHacking/Ocaml/exception_backtraces.html , http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Printexc.html , ...

Comment: I always have `ocamlopt.opt -g` and `ocamlc.opt -g`, and `export OCAMLRUNPARAM=b`, but it still shows nothing for an error which I can catch by `try ... with ...`.

Comment: Also, where should I put commands of `Printexc`? It seems that an exception disappears out of the file where it occurs. So catching the exception at the highest level does not work...